# Week Number, where week starts on Monday (not Sunday)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'm trying to calculate the number of new subscribers, unsubscribes, held, etc, by week where the week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday.  I can get the query to work fine when the week starts on Sunday (which is the default), but can't figure out how to get the week calculate to start on a Monday (which lines up with the customer's internal reporting).

I don't believe I can use `SET DATEFIRST 1` so what are my options?

Here's my code that works with Sunday

```
SELECT 
  SubscriberKey as Email
, DateJoined
, Concat(DatePart(yyyy,DateJoined), '-', DatePart(ww,DateAdd(ww,-4,DateJoined))) as JoinWeek
, DateUnsubscribed
, DateUndeliverable
, Concat(DatePart(yyyy,DateUnsubscribed) , '-', DatePart(ww,DateUnsubscribed)) as UnsubWeek
, Concat(DatePart(yyyy,DateUndeliverable), '-', DatePart(ww,DateUndeliverable)) as UndeliverableWeek
, Status 
FROM _Subscribers  
WHERE DateJoined > DateAdd(d,-30,GetDate())
```

Comment: What if you were to put in case statements, something like: `CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, DateUnsubscribed) = 1 THEN CONCAT(DatePart(yyyy,DateUnsubscribed), ' - ', DateAdd(week,-1, DatePart(ww,DateUnsubscribed)) ELSE Concat(DatePart(yyyy,DateUnsubscribed) , '-', DatePart(ww,DateUnsubscribed)) END as UnsubWeek`. I haven't tested it, so may need some syntax help - but that should push the displayed week back one on Sun. (dw = 1) but leaving it as is for the rest of the week effectively forcing a MON - SUN week.

Comment: @gortonington - YES!  I took what you had and massaged it a little to get to where I need - I will post my code as an Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
  SubscriberKey as Email
, DateJoined
, concat(DatePart(year,DateJoined), '-', right(concat('0',(DATEPART(dy,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101', DateJoined)/7*7,'17530104'))+6)/7),2)) as JoinWeek
, DateUnsubscribed
, DateUndeliverable
, Concat(DatePart(yyyy,DateUnsubscribed) , '-', right(concat('0',(DATEPART(dy,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101', DateUnsubscribed)/7*7,'17530104'))+6)/7),2)) as UnsubWeek
, Concat(DatePart(yyyy,DateUndeliverable), '-', right(concat('0',(DATEPART(dy,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101', DateUndeliverable)/7*7,'17530104'))+6)/7),2)) as UndeliverableWeek
, Status 
FROM _Subscribers  
WHERE DateJoined >= getDate()-30
```

Found the info here on [**this post**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/97910/).  I created a test table in my local database and ran it for every day in 1.5 years and it appears to be correct.

[image: sql test]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @gortonington for nudging me along...

Here's what my SQL ends up as, and it works great.  I should point out - My client's week # is actually back a few weeks, hence the DateAdd component was added.

```
SELECT 
 SubscriberKey as Email,
 DateJoined,
 DateUnsubscribed,
 DateUndeliverable,   
 CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, DateUnsubscribed) = 1 THEN
   CONCAT(DatePart(yyyy,DateUnsubscribed), '-', DatePart(ww,DateAdd(ww,-3,DateUnsubscribed))) ELSE 
   CONCAT(DatePart(yyyy,DateUnsubscribed), '-', DatePart(ww,DateAdd(ww,-4,DateUnsubscribed))) 
   END as UnsubWeek,
CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, DateJoined) = 1 THEN
   CONCAT(DatePart(yyyy,DateJoined), '-', DatePart(ww,DateAdd(ww,-3,DateJoined)))
   ELSE CONCAT(DatePart(yyyy,DateJoined), '-', DatePart(ww,DateAdd(ww,-4,DateJoined))) 
   END as JoinWeek,
CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, DateUndeliverable) = 1 THEN
   CONCAT(DatePart(yyyy,DateUndeliverable), '-', DatePart(ww,DateAdd(ww,-3,DateUndeliverable))) ELSE 
   CONCAT(DatePart(yyyy,DateUndeliverable), '-', DatePart(ww,DateAdd(ww,-4,DateUndeliverable))) 
END as UndeliverableWeek,
Status 
FROM _Subscribers
```